# when static variables destroy in android application??

Tags: variables, static, ondestroy

On calling onDestory(), application runs in background... and static members remain same as in previous access of application...They must have get destroyed on calling onDestroy()

Does onDestroy destroys current activity or whole application?

Comment: Can you develop your question more? what programming language you are talking, etc

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need the objects outside of the lifecycle of the activity then make them member variables.

Otherwise they will be destroyed when the 'application' is destroyed i.e. the application class.

Answer (score 0):

onDestroy of an Activity is run when the activity is ended.  THe application may or may not be totally be removed from memory at that time, depending on memory use of the system and what other activities/services in the application are still running.

Comment: Thanks for the help
But how to remove all activities of an application ? 
Kindly tell me when static members of an application gets destroy?

Comment: When Android decides to.  There's no real way to force this.  It will unload them when it decides it needs to exit the application, generally when there are no running activities or services, or when it runs low of memory and kills a background app to claim its ram.